# symfony1.4 parse/generate plist

Tags: plist, symfony-1.4

I am working with symfony1.4 and I need to parse/generate a plist format.Do you have an idea of ​​the libraries that I can use?

Answer (score 2):

I've used [CFPropertyList on github](https://github.com/rodneyrehm/CFPropertyList) with symfony when I needed to talk back and forth with an iOS app. It does automatic type guessing and supports regular XML and Binary Plist formats.